# Why does Traffic generator tools use libpcap library?

Tags: c++, networking, libpcap

libpcap is a packet capture library. It makes sense to me that packet sniffers/analyzers use it since they capture network traffic and analyze it. Why does a packet generator e.g Ostinato use libpcap? As far as I know, traffic generators do not need to capture packet traffic.

Please help me clarify the confusion.

Thank you.

Comment: just because it's called pcap(ture), doesn't that capturing is **ALL** that the library does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the creator of Ostinato, just want to highlight two things -

1. libpcap/winpcap is not just a packet capture library but also a packet injection library; most importantly, it is cross platform
2. Ostinato (and other traffic generators) support packet capture as well as packet generation

So libpcap/winpcap was an obvious choice for Ostinato

Answer (score 2):

> libpcap is a packet capture library.

It's also, as of libpcap 0.9 (it's currently up to 1.4), a packet injection library, with `pcap_inject()` and `pcap_sendpacket()` APIs (two APIs for backwards compatibility with OpenBSD and WinPcap, but the difference is trivial).